# Calling WCF service from WebApi throws MessageSecurityException

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, wcf-security

I use 3rd party client library which internally communicates with server (somewhere in cloud) using WCF (I only can configure few key/value settings, the library creates all the WCF client proxy stack within its code).

If I use the library in WinForms or console application it works well, however calling the library API from within WebApi it ends up with error:

```
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The Identity check failed for the outgoing message. 
The remote endpoint did not provide a domain name system (DNS) claim and therefore did not satisfied DNS identity 'serverName'. 
This may be caused by lack of DNS or CN name in the remote endpoint X.509 certificate's distinguished name.
```

Why there is a difference? The server side is the same, so does this mean the identity check is not performed when running in WinForms app? Or the identity check is performed differently when running in WebApi? How can I fix it?

I run the code from within VS2015, WebApi is hosted in IISExpress. The library uses `NetTcpBinding` with `TransportWithMessageCredential` and `MessageCredentialType.UserName`

Comment: Is your Winform app and WebApi app targetting the same .Net framework version?

Comment: @JfBeaulac Good point! They're different - WinForm is 4.5.2 while WebApi is 4.6.1. I need to setup test environment to validate, I'll be back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to your app.config file

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IdentityModel.DisableMultipleDNSEntriesInSANCertificate=true" />
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

From MSDN:

> Starting with apps that target the .NET Framework 4.6.1, the X509CertificateClaimSet.FindClaims method will attempt to match the claimType argument with all the DNS entires in its SAN field.
>   Impact
>
> This change only affects apps that target the .NET Framework 4.6.1.
>
> For apps that target previous versions of the .NET Framework, the X509CertificateClaimSet.FindClaims method attempts to match the claimType argument only with the last the DNS entry.
>   Mitigation
>
> If this change is undesirable, apps that target the .NET Framework 4.6.1 can opt out of it by adding the following configuration setting to the  section of the app’s configuration file:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt620030%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I can confirm that after downgrading .NET framework (I tested 4.5.2 and 4.6.0) it works. But with 4.6.1 the setting does not help. I even copied it directly from MSDN to avoid typo issue. The same with WinForm app so at least the behavior is consistent.

Comment: The server runs Windows but is not in any domain, neither the client PC. With a help of decompiler I found out the server sets certificate (ServiceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate) but NetTcpBinding.Security.Transport.TcpClientCredentialType is not set, which means Windows is used by default. My understanding is that if the TcpClientCredentialType was set to Certificate, it should have worked. But with Windows it shouldn't as the endpoints are not in the same windows domain.

Comment: @eXavier for some reason adding AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.IdentityModel.DisableMultipleDNSEntriesInSANCertificate", true); worked when the app.config change did not.